# Setting android:gradientRadius via Java

Tags: android

Is it possible to set android:gradientRadius of a drawable via Java or is it only possible to set this attribute via Xml?

Answer (score 2):

The `GradientDrawable` class has the `setGradientRadius(float)` method, so as long as whatever drawable you are trying to modify extends that class, yes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html